# what is the relation between electric conductivity and permittivity in the steady state?

Tags: electric-fields

[image]I find good answers like http://pleclair.ua.edu/impedance/The%20Relationship%20Between%20Loss.pdf for the case that there is a omega!=0 (equation 11), but what about the trivial (?) steady state?

Background: I want to calculate the E-field of two electrodes in the presence of two media - marine water and sediment and a metal conductor. Both water and sediment have specific permittivity and conductivity, and those would both have an influence on how the electic field is formed.  I facilitate electical mirror charges to calculate the electric potential field, neglecting the conductivity, and get reasonable results, but I need help with bringing the conductivity into the equation. you can find my calculations here: https://cocalc.com/share/f7766c5e-2f4d-4916-bb0d-74a7182e5fd5/E-Feld-2019-03-12-114056.sagews?viewer=share